# How to read all spss files in a folder in pandas? and concatenate them

Tags: python, python-3.x, spss

I would like to read several SAV files (SPSS) from a directory into pandas and concatenate them into one big DataFrame. I have not been able to figure it out though. Here is what I have so far:

```
    path = r'\C:\abc\path'
    all_files = glob.glob(path + "\*.sav")
    
    df_list = []
    
    for filename in all_files:
        df = pd.read_spss(filename,convert_categoricals=False)
        df_list.append(filename)
    
    pd.concat(df_list)
```

**I am getting the error below.**

```
OverflowError: date value out of range
```

**The below code is running fine but I am getting error when I am looping through files and reading them.**

```
df = pd.read_spss(all_files[0])
```

Comment: See https://github.com/Roche/pyreadstat#known-limitations

Answer (score 0):

When you append an element to the list, I think you should add the df instead of filename, like this:

```
df_list.append(df)
```

Comment: Yes, you are right but the issue is `pd.read_spss` is not reading some files and getting this error `OverflowError: date value out of range`

Comment: Have you tried to delete "convert_categoricals=False"? or There is a new version of read_spss (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_spss.html) Maybe you should update the code with the new version, because sometimes the previous ones are outdated

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import glob

path = r'\C:\abc\path'
all_files = glob.glob(path + "\*.sav")

df_list = []

for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_spss(filename, convert_categoricals=False, dates_as_pandas_datetime=False)
    df_list.append(df)

merged_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)
```

Here is my solution to my problem.